# How do you extract the user data from the json and send it to a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, twitter

```
string url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json";                          
string data = oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(oAuthTwitter.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);
```

i m integrating twitter login to my site i m getiing all user data to string data variable.Now i have to read user value from data string. can any body tell how to this json string value.

Comment: The easiest way is to add the Json.NET NuGet package, create an class that matches the structure of the response, and deserialize. Examples here: http://james.newtonking.com/json

Comment: thanks joe for your input